# Translating custom coordinate system for MyCoordSysDefs.fme

Tags: coordinate-system, fme-form

I have a custom coordinate system that I was confused how to translate it to the MyCoordSysDefs.fme for use in Safe Desktop. Here's how it is represented in the prj file:

```
GEOGCS['GCS_ETRS_1989',DATUM['D_ETRS_1989',SPHEROID['GRS_1980',6378137.0,298.257222101]],
PRIMEM['Greenwich',0.0],UNIT['Degree',0.0174532925199433]],VERTCS['EVRF_2007',VDATUM['European_Vertical_Reference_Frame_2007'],
PARAMETER['Vertical_Shift',0.0],PARAMETER['Direction',1.0],UNIT['Meter',1.0]]
```

I read over the help for FME Desktop, but the I did not know how to translate it because it had two units and so many parameters.

Comment: What is intended here, do you need the vertical aspect (height) or the data content? If the data aspect is important, you could project it to an other CRS.

Comment: Support for vertical datums was added to the EsriReprojector very recently - it's in 2022 beta in fact. There is no documentation yet so I've asked our developers and they are getting me some screenshots and other info that I can share with you.

Answer (score 0):

The [European Vertical Reference Frame 2007](http://www.euref.eu/symposia/2008Brussels/01-04-SACHER%20-%20EVRF2007.pdf) belongs to the [pan-European Coordinate Reference Systems](http://crs.bkg.bund.de/definition-crs.htm) and [addresses land/ sea based height normalization efforts](http://www.euref.eu/documentation/Tutorial2015/t-03-01-Sacher.pdf) of the EU between 1994 and 2019.

- [EVRF2007_AMST / NH](http://crs.bkg.bund.de/crseu/crs/eu-description.php?crs_id=Y0VWUkYyMDA3X0FNU1QrJTJGK05I) **normal heights** of the UELN adjustment of 2008 in relation to the tide gauge Amsterdam (NAP) (also known as EVRF2007)
- EVRF2007_AMST / CP **geopotential numbers** of the UELN adjustment of 2008 in relation to the tide gauge Amsterdam (NAP) (also known as EVRF2007).
- Height: https://epsg.io/5621
- Datum: https://epsg.io/5215-datum
- ETRS98 + Height: https://epsg.io/7423

I'm afraid you have to go through the documentations of your incoming data source to know what is stored there. IMO EPSG 7423 is addressed here.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so you'll need FME2022, build 22255 or greater. Currently, only 22245 is available on the website, so you'll have to wait a little while anyway. Plus it's still in beta, in case that's important to you.

I put together a short video demo that you can find here: https://youtu.be/U_0JlsTd5Bg

Basically:

1. Separate the horizontal and vertical information from your prj into separate prj files.
2. Place an EsriReprojector transformer.
3. Under Horizontal, Source Coordinate System, click ... and then choose import.
4. Select the prj file for your horizontal coordinate system
5. Under Vertical, Source Coordinate System, click ... and then choose import.
6. Select the prj file for your vertical datum

Now you can reproject data from that coordinate system to another.